# Conditions ensuring that a compact set can be approximated by approximating its distance function

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, semicontinuity, set-valued-analysis

Let $\emptyset\neq K\subset Y$ be a closed subset of a compact metric space $(X,d)$ such that $K$ has at-least two points and such that
$$
d(Y,K):=\sup_{y\in Y}\,\inf_{k\in K}\,d(k,y)=:r>0.
$$
Define $d_K(x):=\inf_{z\in K}\, d(x,z)$ and let $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be lower semi-continuous and such that
$$
\max_{x\in X}\, \big|f(x)-d_K(x)\big|<r/2.
$$

Define the levelset $K_f:=\{x\in X:\, f(x)\leq r/2\}$ and suppose that $K_f\neq \emptyset$ (e.g. by assuming that $f^{-1}[\{0\}]\neq \emptyset$).

---

**Question:**

What (non-trivial) conditions on the pair $K$ and $Y$ need to be imposed to ensure that, $K_f\subseteq Y$?

---

**A Sufficient Condition:**
Clearly, something like for some $x\in X$ set $Y=Ball_X(x,2r)$ and $K=Ball_X(x,r)$ works.

More generally, if we assume that $Y=K_r:=\{x\in X:\,d_K(x)<r\}$ then everything checks out.

**When things don't work:**
However, [the counterexample of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486344/approximating-a-compact-set-by-approximating-its-distance-function/4486357#4486357) still works: i.e. $K$ is the same, $Y=K\cup \{\tilde{x}\}$ where $d(\tilde{x},K)=r$ and $X$ is such that there exists some $y\in X\setminus K\cup\{\tilde{x}\}$ such that $d_K(y)<r/2$.